# Updating a value from a table that is dependent on the value of an ENUM column in another table

Tags: mysql, enums, sql-update, dateadd

I have one table `placed_order` that contains the columns `order_time` (timestamp), `estimated_delivery_time` (timestamp) and more. In a second table `addresses` there is the column `zone` (apart from others). 
The `zone` column is an ENUM field and contains the values 'Zone 1', 'Zone 2', 'Zone 3'.

Now I need to calculate the `estimated_delivery_time`. Depending on the zones, it is the `order_time` plus 10mins (Zone 1), 15mins (Zone 2) ord 20mins (Zone 3).

I already found out how to calculate the `estimated_delivery_time` by manually adding the minutes:

```
UPDATE `placed_order` 
SET `estimated_delivery_time` = DATE_ADD(`order_time`, INTERVAL 10 MINUTE)
WHERE placed_order_id = 9;
```

But I'm absolutely struggling to find a solution how the `estimated_delivery_time` can be calculated depending on the zones. I already tried it with SELECT IF and CASE clauses but couldn't find a way. Any suggestions?

Comment: Look at the [multitable update](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html) syntax and a [case](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html#operator_case) statement to resolve zones to time intervals.

Comment: How do you connect the two tables ? What is the join relationship ?

Comment: Both tables have the 'customer_id' (PK from a third table 'customers' as a Foreign Key. Is that enough to connect them?

Comment: @dandelia check the posted answer. Thanks

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya It works!! I really appreciate your fast help! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`Case .. When`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html#operator_case) to update the `estimated_delivery_time`. Try the following query:

```
UPDATE `placed_order` AS po 
JOIN `addresses` AS addr ON addr.customer_id = po.customer_id 
SET po.estimated_delivery_time = CASE addr.zone 
                                   WHEN 'Zone 1' 
                                     THEN DATE_ADD(po.order_time, INTERVAL 10 MINUTE)
                                   WHEN 'Zone 2' 
                                     THEN DATE_ADD(po.order_time, INTERVAL 15 MINUTE)
                                   WHEN 'Zone 3' 
                                     THEN DATE_ADD(po.order_time, INTERVAL 20 MINUTE)
                                 END
```